# Bendable Construction Material

Tags: science-fiction, construction, earthquake

I need to find a construction material with the following properties:

1) Flexibility: The material should be able to bend itself 90 to 180 degrees. This property is needed to survive an earthquake weapon the enemy utilises. Current Non Bendable buildings collapse from the earthquake. The earthquake weapon is several times stronger than normal natural earthquakes.

2) Maintenance: The material should be able to last several years without maintenance. Ideally, complete material replacement should happen after 100 years.

Comment: 180 degrees: this building can fold itself in half?  I want a little more building than that around me in an earthquake, please.  I can only fold 120 degrees on a limber day.

Comment: That is not well formed.  Any physical material will have some flex and a *suitabky long* piece can turn 180°.  Also, why don’t your walls fall over on a normal day?

Comment: *"The earthquake weapon is several times stronger than normal natural earthquakes:"* what does this mean? Natural earthquakes span an enormous gamut of "strengths" (= energy released), and the most powerful ones are capable of massively re-arranging the landscape.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For flexibility, you should look more at the structure than at the material choices.  With the correct structure, many materials can be tremendously flexible.  Also, you need more than flexibility.  *Many* things are flexible, but you need them to be rigid enough to support a load as well, and return to normal afterwards.

**Wood can meet your needs:**
[image: Trees]
Properly organized, wood is sufficiently flexible to let palm trees bend out of the way of hurricane force winds.

**Steel can meet your needs:**
[image: Steel flexing]
Steel comes in more variants than you can study in a lifetime!  Some of them are very rigid and brittle, but others are remarkably flexible.

**Glass can be flexible:**
[image: Glass spring]
Just to show how many materials can meet these needs, with a water cutter one can even cut a glass spring!  Even glass flexes when shaped correctly!

**What you really care about is structure.**

This, of course, is a good thing for you.  If materials was the only thing that mattered, you could be in trouble.  In general, the ability to flex dramatically and longevity are opposing desires.  Most things which flex break down quickly because they have many degrees of freedom.  Cross-linked rubber would be amazing for the flexibility requirement you need, but does wear out under UV radiation.
[image: Radiator hose]

Earthquake proof buildings are constructed with the same steel, glass, and concrete that other buildings are.  However, they structure them to be resistant to the particular loads an earthquake can cause.  For example, to combat a longitudinal wave, such buildings are often built on giant steel ball bearing-like joints which permit the building to rock back and forth in an earthquake.
[image: Spherical Sliding Isolator]

One can also take lessons from the ancient Japanese.  They designed entire pagodas to flex at many joints to combat earthquakes, as can be seen in the computer simulations below.  Nothing was nailed down in these buildings.  In fact, many of them were later moved to America, simply by pushing out the wooden pins holding everything together, disassembling the parts, and reassembling them.
[image: Pagoda sim]

These may be of particular interest to you because many of these buildings are hundreds of years old, meeting your durability requirements as well, using nothing but wood and careful construction!

Comment: For glass, Olympic bows are significant example. Glass fiber on front and back.

Comment: "Even glass flexes when shaped correctly!" Yeah, but you have to be a polishing demon. Unless *every* surface flaw is removed, stress concentrations will cause it to fail in remarkably snort time.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast "Snort time"? I believe that's another type of glass.

Comment: @Joachim - It's a technical term related to the "ohnosecond", which measures the extremely short time between realizing that you should NOT send that email and your finger actually hitting the mouse button or Enter key.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are looking for construction material which is flexible, cost-effective and durable then GLASS FIBER REINFORCED POLYMER (GFRP) REBAR is one of the best and popular construction materials. There are lots of civil engineering applications where this material is being used successfully. Its durable, cost-effective and corrosion free.
You can read the major [benefits of GFRP rebar here](https://www.tuf-bar.com/advantages-of-using-glass-fiber-reinforced-polymer-gfrp-rebar/).

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! Firstly, is this material bendable to the degree that the question specifies? Would a building constructed from it survive a severe earthquake? Secondly, are you affiliated with the company you linked in your answer? At the moment, this reads more like an advert for their GFRP supplies than an honest attempt to answer the question.